# Smarty convert unix timestamp to days left

Tags: date, smarty, date-format

Is there a plugin of function in smarty, or anything else i can to do make smarty convert unix timestamp to the "weeks/days/hours left until that date"? I know i can do it in php, but it is more convenient to do it in smarty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to do it in PHP, why don't you just make it available to smarty as a function or modifier plugin? See [Extending Smarty With Plugins](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.tpl).

(and no, smarty doesn't come with a core plugin that does what you need)